# How can i get globals() for calling Python script with subprocess()?

Tags: python

I want to use a script to call another script run.py

```
# main.py
import subprocess
import sys

def fn():
    print('I am fn...')

fpath = '/Users/runtest/run.py'

def run_with_exec():
    with open(fpath, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
        code = f.read()
    exec(compile(code.encode("utf-8"), fpath, 'exec'), globals())

def run_with_subprocess():
    subprocess.run([sys.executable, fpath])  # Just run the program

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_with_exec()
    run_with_subprocess()
```

The run_with_exec() run can send globals(), and the called script run.py can use the fn() function in main.py.
But how can I run with run_with_subprocess() to make the called script run.py use the fn() function in main.py?
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: What's your use case here? Why do you ant to use subprocess? Why don't you just want to import a file and call a function normally?

Comment: The file being called will change， like run a script in IDE.

Comment: You can import files dynamically with `importlib.import_module(module_name)`. Even apart from that, `exec` should still work.

Comment: Thanks in advance. Let me try.

Comment: I tried the 'import_module()',But the key is I want to run 'run.py' in main.py then 'fn()' can be called in 'run.py',if i use 'import_module' it will causing circular references.

Comment: You should probably be passing `fn` as an argument to a function inside `run.py`. That's called a higher order function. Or if you want `fn` to be magically available to `run` as if it's defined there, try `run_module.fn = fn`. Or just put `fn` in a module other than `main` and have `run` import from there instead.

Comment: fn() called in run.py it can be complied before 'run_module.fn = fn'

Comment: Don't call `fn` at the top level, call it inside a function which main is responsible for calling. Or rather stick to one of my other two suggestions. A third module is probably best.

Comment: okay, It seems that I can only separates fn() from main. Thank you for your answer.